# Adding overlay search to wordpress using add action/filter

Tags: customization, filters, search, actions

I want to add custom overlay search to my WordPress site using add action. Somehow, it is not triggering the javascripts to show the overlay html. However, it is working in a browser when I test simply in browser by saving as html, [can be checked here](https://js.do/code/overlayworkingcode). How can I properly add them n functions.php to run these codes.

Here is my codes which I add to functions.php. Even, the scripts are also present when the page loads. The searchbox contains the onclick event.

The form code

```
<form method="get" id="search" action="https://tatest.tutorialsart.com/">
    <input id="search-input"  inputmode="search" onclick="openSearch()" type="text" name="s" title="Search for" placeholder="Search for" />
        <button id="search-submit" type="submit">
                <span class="tie-icon-search tie-search-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for</span>
        </button>
                
 </form>
```

The scripts for triggering the overlay in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'Search_trigger_script' );
function Search_trigger_script() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function openSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "block";
}

function closeSearch() {
  document.getElementById("myOverlay").style.display = "none";
}

</script>
<?php
}
```

The html overlay code in functions.php

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'Search_overlay_html' );
function Search_overlay_html() {
?>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.openBtn {
  background: #f1f1f1;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.openBtn:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}

.overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}

.overlay-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 2%;
  width: 80%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin: auto;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 45px;
  font-size: 60px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}

.overlay .closebtn:hover {
  color: #ccc;
}

.overlay input[type=text] {
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: white;
}

.overlay input[type=text]:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.overlay button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 15px;
  background: #ddd;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.overlay button:hover {
  background: #bbb;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myOverlay" class="overlay">
  <span class="closebtn" onclick="closeSearch()" title="Close Overlay">×</span>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html> 

<?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added the ajax script

```
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and the z-index for the the overlay has to be higher than any other styles. The onclick event was working hewer the results were not appearing. Setting z-index value higher showed the results working. So

```
  .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to edit your searchform.php file. If you are using get_search_form(); [read this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_form/) . In case you use search widget you need to override the Widget.

If you dont want to use searchform.php you can go with filter:

```
function wpdocs_my_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="' . home_url( '/' ) . '" >
    <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __( 'Search for:' ) . '</label>
    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'" />
    </div>
    </form>';
 
    return $form;
}
add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'wpdocs_my_search_form' );
```

After that your wordpress search form should contain onclick="openSearch()". You can use Twenty twenty one theme as example. I have tested your code and its working. See screenshots - https://prnt.sc/1qloaxz https://prnt.sc/1qlof07

I would just go with JS or jQuery to target the overlay form.

```
 JS
    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var element = document.getElementsByClassName('target-class');
              element.onclick = function() {
                  alert('Success');
              }
        }
    </script>

jQuery
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery('.target-class').click(function() {
            alert('Success');
        });
    });
</script>
```